# how to use TabID?

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke, response.redirect, navigateurl

i wanna access a link using tab id instead of Static URL as my URl is

```
Response.Redirect("~/Activities/Calendar.aspx?date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

and i use the following Code

```
Dim objModuleController As DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleController
Dim objModuleInfo As DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleInfo = objModuleController.GetModule(CInt(CType(Settings("DetailsCalendar"), Integer)))
Dim TabID As Integer = objModuleInfo.TabID

If CBool(CType(Settings("DetailsCalendar"), String)) Then
    Response.Redirect(NavigateURL(TabID, "date", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")))
End If
```

but it redirect me to a wrong URL 
what am i doing wrong or how to write it , i adon know how to use TabID with URLs

Comment: And what problem are you having? There doesn't appear to be a question here

Comment: it redirect me to wrong URL , how could i use Tabid to access the url in the Responce.Redirect ?

Answer (score 1):

If your control inherits "PortalModuleBase" it already has the TabId on it.

But the root cause of your issues with Navigate Url is that the structure that it has is similar to the following for the overload you are trying

```
NavigateUrl(int TabId, string contolKey, string[] params)
```

You need to pass the values so you are only appending the params

From your example you should be fine with

```
NavigateUrl(TabId, string.Empty, "date", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

The key here is that you are not passing a control key.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code which make it works :)

```
Dim objModuleController As New DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleController
Dim objModuleInfo As DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleInfo = objModuleController.GetModule(CInt(CType(Settings("DetailsCalendar"), Integer)))

If CBool(CType(Settings("DetailsCalendar"), String)) Then
IF (objModuleInfo.TabID <> 0 ) Then
Response.Redirect(NavigateURL(objModuleInfo.TabID, String.Empty ,"date="+ DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")))
End If
End If
```